Force Word interop to use multiple instances of Word at once
I've found myself with a bit of an odd problem and I can't seem to work out what may be causing it. We have a system which has a process inside of it to convert files to PDF format. To do this we are using Word Interop. This is done by starting an external process from a service which itself starts Word like the below:
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = null;
try
{
    application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    application.Application.Visible = false;
    application.Visible = false;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = application.Documents.Open(tempSource, Visible: false, ReadOnly: true, NoEncodingDialog: true, AddToRecentFiles: false);
    doc.SaveAs2(tempDestination, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
    doc.Close(false);
}
finally
{
    application?.Quit();
}

On our server with Word 2013 installed we can have multiple instances of this running at once and Word will process them all concurrently showing multiple Word instances in Task Manager. However, on a customer site, also with Word 2013 installed, it seems that no matter how many of our external processes are open Word itself is restricted to one instance and will only open the next as the first finishes up.
Does anyone know how I can get around this and force Word to process multiple at once?
Due to the nature of this problem I can't seem to find much help on the matter and most articles point to solutions like DesktopAppsAlwaysLaunchNewInstance or using the -X command line parameter, neither of which apply here. I also found out about DisableMergeInstance but this appears to be an Excel only thing and also isn't set on our server anyway for Word.

That's no solution to any problem and means you used a hack to generate PDFs, one that  violates Word licensing too - you need one license for every end user. If you use Word on a server, you need one license for every single user that uses your web app or service, even if they're anonymous.

@PanagiotisKanavos It is only one user using the service, you're just assuming web services when I didn't state as such. There is no license issue here so you don't need to worry about it.

You need to worry about it, ensure you buy a license for any user using your service. And that the operation will be orders of magnitude slower than actually generating PDFs. You can argue it's not wrong or you can wait so I can tell you what it is you're trying to do and why it will probably not work. Word isn't a server application

@PanagiotisKanavos We do have a license for every user... i.e. the only one. This is a Windows service on a server which monitors a directory for files and converts them to .pdfs. This also does work correctly and has done for years, It is just that it has recently come to our attention that on some servers it will run multiple instances of Word at once and others it will force single instance.

The real problem is that PDF generation is done in a quick&very-dirty way, using Word to print-to-PDF.  Word isn't a server application and Word Interop is meant to control a single instance of Word. Word Interop is actually a COM Automation API. That means you get the same running  instance every time you ask for the same application type or rather, Class ID. The threading model is ENTIRELY up to the COM server application, ie Word. If you use the Class ID you always get the running version. If you use eg a doc path you may get a different instance - or not.

None of this is new - that's how COM always worked, all the way back to the 1990s. new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();. In some versions, Word would start the main App and use a different window for every document, to save memory. In other versions, a different instance would run for every document to avoid one crash killing all documents. When things got more reliable, a single main app was used again. Nowadays I think parts of Office are loaded on startup. I have no idea what was going on 11 years ago.

@PanagiotisKanavos It's not the problem whether it's opening within itself or a new instance. The problem is that it is not opening at all until the previous instance has closed. It is completely queuing up the calls to Word synchronously and there is no concurrent processing going on. But only on some servers not on them all. Unless I've misunderstood what you're saying I think you may have misunderstood what the problem is.

The code you posted would only cause serial execution if the actual Word instance is not closed by the way.  Calling Quit doesn't dispose application nor does it release the COM pointer held by the object. This will happen when garbage collection runs. There are several similar questions asking why the instance remains after closing, like this one. In general, using Office interop the way you tried has a lot of traps, and this is one of the most annoying

I have used interop for pdf generation in the past, But this approach depends on the word installation & configuration. It is not something I would trust running unsupervised. For anything running on a server I would take a look at converting word to pdf without interop.

@PanagiotisKanavos The instance does not remain though and in the question you link isn't the answer to use Quit which we already are using?

@JonasH Unfortunately, this is a small part of a larger system and it is a pain to make such a large change with the system having been in place for years at this point. We really have to stick to the original design as much as possible which means sticking with Word interop if possible even if it isn't exactly recommended nowadays.

No. That's the minimum requirement, followed by GC.Collect and other attempts to immediatelly release the COM object. does not remain the behavior says it does. There's a reason people that used COM interop in the 2000s abandoned it as soon as possible. Word just isn't meant to work the way you want. To make it work you really need to understand how COM interop works, the COM lifecycle AND the quirks of an 11-year old Word version AND the quirks of the specific installation. If Word 2013 starts a single app because of a domain policy, there's nothing your code can do

AND in the 2013 timeframe Microsoft was pushing Excel and Word Services in SharePoint, which means they felt free to treat the desktop versions as single-user ones. If someone complained they could point at the free Word Services versions available

In any case, DesktopAppsAlwaysLaunchNewInstance will never work. You're not starting Word from the Windows Shell, you're starting it directly

@PanagiotisKanavos I know that, I said it doesn't apply here. I was just using it to show some of things I'd come across whilst researching myself.

It's completely irrelevant and shows you're looking at the wrong direction. What you ask is weirder the more I think about it though. The current code creates and destroys an Word instance for every document, something really slow. Using a single application instance to process documents in a loop could result in orders of magnitude better performance. What you call "concurrent" processing isn't either - you can't run more threads at the same time than there are CPU cores after all. On a 4-core, starting 100 Word instances will result in worse performance than 4 due to thrashing

How many cores does the customer machine have, or rather, how many cores is your process allowed to use? If it's only 1, Word actually saved you from a livelock situation that wouldn't allow any document to complete.

@PanagiotisKanavos Yes I know that I can't create more threads than cores (or logical processors) and we are not doing that. The server CPU has 8 cores and even if we only ask it to process 4 or less at once it will still always only ever do 1 at a time. Our code runs 4 instances of our app to process the docs but they all halt and Word will only run one at once. (On our server Word will open all 4, it seems to be some configuration issue for the customer).

And to be clear, I know it is slow but I've dumbed down the system and with the way it all works, for better or worse, it isn't possible to keep one application open and use that each time we need to process a document.

The following may be of interest: Considerations for server-side Automation of Office

The usage of Office that you've described isn't supported and is unlikely to work reliably.
